# Compare kCFFTPResourceType to number

Tags: ios, xcode, cfstream

I am writing an FTP download system, the the listing function:

```
NSLog(@"%@", listDir.filesInfo);
```

I see my files on server:

```
{
    kCFFTPResourceGroup = group;
    kCFFTPResourceLink = "";
    kCFFTPResourceModDate = "2012-11-04 15:49:00 +0000";
    kCFFTPResourceMode = 511;
    kCFFTPResourceName = "eyeview__0000_sport_general.jpg";
    kCFFTPResourceOwner = owner;
    kCFFTPResourceSize = 169790;
    kCFFTPResourceType = 8;
},
    {
    kCFFTPResourceGroup = group;
    kCFFTPResourceLink = "";
    kCFFTPResourceModDate = "2012-11-04 15:49:00 +0000";
    kCFFTPResourceMode = 511;
    kCFFTPResourceName = "eyeview__0001_sport_reading.jpg";
    kCFFTPResourceOwner = owner;
    kCFFTPResourceSize = 224795;
    kCFFTPResourceType = 8;
},
```

The next thing I wish to do is:

```
for (NSDictionary *file in listDir.filesInfo)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName]); //Prints the file name

        if ([file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceType]==8) //*My problem
        {
            [filesList addObject:[file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName]]; //Works perfectly in case outside the if function
        }


    }
```

*My problem is the comparison wrong, how can I write it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[file objectForKey:]` won't return an `int`. It returns an `NSNumber` (aka `CFNumberRef`).

Demo:

```
NSNumber * n = [file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceType];
const int i = n.intValue;
if (8 == i) {
  [filesList addObject:[file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful when the kCFFTPResourceType details are needed.

[kCFFTPResourceType details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html)